# Exporting Network Analyst layer objects (orders, routes, etc) created in Python after solve?

Tags: arcpy, layers, network-analyst, feature-layer, error-000732

I'm trying to export Orders dataset after solving a Vehicle Routing Problem (VRP) into a shapefile using Python only. The problem is that apparently arcpy without mxd open doesn't recognise my VRP layer. Below is the code I'm working on:

```
outNALayer = arcpy.na.MakeVehicleRoutingProblemLayer (inNetworkDataset, 
                                                      outNALayerName, 
                                                      "Time", 
                                                      "Length", 
                                                      "Minutes", 
                                                      "Meters", 
                                                      "", 
                                                      "", 
                                                      "High", 
                                                      "Low", 
                                                      "ALLOW_DEAD_ENDS_ONLY", 
                                                      ["Oneway","Speed"], 
                                                      "NO_HIERARCHY", 
                                                      "", 
                                                      "NO_LINES")
outNALayer = outNALayer.getOutput(0)

#Get the names of all the sublayers within the VRP layer.
subLayerNames = arcpy.na.GetNAClassNames(outNALayer)
#Stores the layer names that we will use later
ordersLayerName = subLayerNames["Orders"]
depotsLayerName = subLayerNames["Depots"]
routesLayerName = subLayerNames["Routes"]
pairsLayerName = subLayerNames["OrderPairs"]

arcpy.na.AddLocations(outNALayer, ordersLayerName, inOrders, orderFieldMappings,"")

#List name of attributes in Depot layer
depotFieldMappings = arcpy.na.NAClassFieldMappings(outNALayer, depotsLayerName)
arcpy.na.AddLocations(outNALayer, depotsLayerName, inDepots, depotFieldMappings, "")

#List name of attributes in Route layer
routeFieldMappings = arcpy.na.NAClassFieldMappings(outNALayer, routesLayerName)
arcpy.na.AddLocations(outNALayer, routesLayerName, inRoutes,  routeFieldMappings, "")

#List name of attributes in Route layer
pairFieldMappings = arcpy.na.NAClassFieldMappings(outNALayer, pairsLayerName)
arcpy.na.AddLocations(outNALayer, pairsLayerName, inPairs,  pairFieldMappings, "")

arcpy.na.Solve(outNALayer, "SKIP")
#arcpy.management.SaveToLayerFile(outNALayer,outLayerFile,"ABSOLUTE")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(outNALayerName + r"\Orders", inOrders + '_' + str(iterator))
```

The error message is that the Orders does not exist or is not supported. I have tried saving the layer file on the disk and accessing Orders from that layer but get the same error. Is there a solution to access the actual sublayers within solved layer just in python. I think Select function is available in model builder only.
Note: the above code runs just fine when is run in the mxd python window.

The error is at the last line. The error message is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\zarem\OneDrive\Total_Transport_Home\Code\Vehicle Routing
>   Problem_Only - Copy.py", line 143, in 
>       arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(outNALayerName + r"\Orders", inOrders + '_' + str(iterator))   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 2435, in
>   CopyFeatures
>       raise e ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset VRP_Lyr_Grp_74\Orders does not
>   exist or is not supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the bit of code to access the sublayers within NA layer.

```
OrderSublayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(outNALayer, "Orders")[0]
```

Hope this helps someone with same problem.